# Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Tags: python, pandas

I have 1.csv likes this

```
Date,Time,Price,Trading volume
20200302,93044896073,2812,100
20200302,93354807451,2825,200
20200302,93527007735,2829,100
20200302,93636557182,2839,100
```

Here Date and Time are in separate column. Attached them with following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df = df.head(3)
df['DateTime'] = df['Date'].astype(str) + df['Time'].astype(str)
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].str[:-6].astype(str)
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

Following code is giving error

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']))
data_ask = df['Price'].resample('1Min').ohlc()
```

The error is as follows:

```
Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the result of `set_index` to the dataframe.

Replace:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']))
```

by:

```
df = df.set_index('DateTime')
```

```
>>> df['Price'].resample('1Min').ohlc()
                       open    high     low   close
DateTime
2020-03-02 09:30:00  2812.0  2812.0  2812.0  2812.0
2020-03-02 09:31:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-03-02 09:32:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-03-02 09:33:00  2825.0  2825.0  2825.0  2825.0
2020-03-02 09:34:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-03-02 09:35:00  2829.0  2829.0  2829.0  2829.0
2020-03-02 09:36:00  2839.0  2839.0  2839.0  2839.0
```